# How to replace fixture generator on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use FactoryGirl instead of default fixtures in edge Rails 3. I used

http://github.com/pjb3/rails3-generators

and tried to do the replacement as adviced in

http://paulbarry.com/articles/2010/01/13/customizing-generators-in-rails-3

this way (config/application.rb)

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.orm             :active_record
  g.template_engine :erb
  g.test_framework  :test_unit, :fixture => true
  g.fixture_replacement "factory_girl", :dir => "test/factories"
end
```

looks good, isn't it? But it does not work ... any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems that the proper way to do it (at least for now :)) is slightly different:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.orm             :active_record
  g.template_engine :erb
  g.test_framework  :test_unit, :fixture_replacement => :factory_girl
end
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Googled for "g.fixture_replacement" and found this in second place after the blog from paulberry

Comment: This works for me, but any idea how to change the factories directory for now?

Comment: This wasn't the reason - see @dvdplm's answer.

Answer (score 7):

For Rails 3.1.rc1 you need "gem 'rails3-generators'" in your Gemfile for the factory_girl fixture replacement to work.